# Whats the best method to Bulk Insert Data in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba

I need to bulk insert a data into SQL server. Need opinion on what is the best method for it. I have three ways to store my file which needs to be bulk inserted:

1. Into any shared drive location (company's shared drives)
2. Into any cloud storage location (like S3, Google Drive)
3. Into any version control share system (like SharePoint, Ignite)

Since our company has bought an AWS server, there are a lot of permission grants issues being faced with bulk insert. What will be the best way so as to get minimum requirements to insert my data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends mostly on where the SQL Server is.

If it's on-premise, then your best bet is to load the data from a shared drive (if possible from a local drive of the server).

If it's on AWS, then S3 will be a better option if the size of your data is within a reasonable limit. It will also depend on the network speed for uploads where ever you are located.

If the server is on AWS, and there are PBs of data to move, then you can consider AWS Snowball.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Jayachandran. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hybrid-method. Keeping your files archived on a share in your on-premise server. Then you copy the file(s) that need to be processed to your AWS Server and delete it after processing.

That way you have a solid and easily reachable archive and no serious needs for resources within AWS.

Comment: This sounds interesting. I think we can do this. thanks, Steef. :)